# How to set a click() Jquery event delay to click again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to set a delay time on my click event to click again, to this prevent multiples clicks in less than 200ms. Example:

```
(delay 200ms){ 
    $('#button').click(function(){
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
   //do stuff
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).prop('disabled', false);
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *rebind* the click event with a `setTimeout` and unbind **within** the click handler(whenever the next click occurs) like

```
function bindClick(){
    $('#button').bind('click',function(){
        ...click code here...

        $('#button').unbind('click');
       setTimeout(bindClick, 200);
    });
}
```

Note, this will not rebind every 200 ms, only when a click occurs.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hanawaxata/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: `setInterval` - you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, this will rebind in 200 ms

Comment: And again, and again, and again, and again.

Comment: No it wont, unless the user clicks the button. This code is within the click handler

Comment: [Again, are you sure?](http://jsbin.com/leyucifuni/1/edit?html,js,console,output) Click the button. It doesn't matter where that function is located, the *global* function `setInterval` has access to that scope now. In fact, click it a few times and watch the intervals stack up.

Comment: @Oka, WOW, I am not focused :). I meant settimeout. Thanks for the major correction!